# Change the border colour of selectinput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to change the border colour of a particular `selectInput`default colour grey to red. After inspecting the HTML I figured out the css parameter that controls the border colour. Then I used HTML tags shown in following code and was able to successfully change the border colour for both the `selectInput`. The problem is that I want to change the colour only for the first select input i.e `Select1` and not `Select2`. Is it possible to change the border colour only one particular `selectinput`?

```
 library(shiny)

  ui <- fluidPage(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML( ".selectize-input {border: 1px solid #dd4b39;}"))),

    selectInput("Select1", "Option1", choices = NULL),

    selectInput("Select2", "Option2", choices = NULL)
  )


  server <- function(input, output){

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: try `tags$head(tags$style("#Select1{border: 1px solid #dd4b39;}")),`

Comment: @Smich7, thank you for your response. Had already tried that earlier. I doesn't work :(

Comment: That's weird, I just edited, have you tried to remove the `HTML` ?

Comment: Yes. I have dropped the HTML, it still doesn't work.

Comment: After searching some more, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/1DXjpB_uaRA) link. Using the answer suggested in the link `tags$head(tags$style(HTML( "#Select1 ~ .selectize-control.single .selectize-input {border: 1px solid #dd4b39;}"))),` seems to work.